# Are there still Leap Years in the Star Trek Universe?

Tags: star-trek, time

I mean, if you are able to travel at warp speed, you should be able to come up with a viable calendar.

What canon information is there regarding whether or not somebody boldly fixed the *Leap Year* flaw that Earth currently uses to reset their calendars?

Comment: I mean, leap year is not really a flaw in the calendar, it's a flaw in the Earth's orbit if anything.

Comment: Agreed @zeldredge. It's not like the leap year is some hack they came up with to fix a miscalculation when they set the length of the day and year. It's just a quirk of the relationship between Earth's rotation and revolution intervals.

Comment: Earth is constantly slowing down. Having a leap year is much preferable to having the day to be 23 hours 59 minutes 49 seconds long (or whatever the current time is...)

Comment: @Petersaber The rotation rate of the earth on its axis isn't really related time it takes to orbit the sun.

Comment: @Zoredache No, it isn't. But the real time to orbit the sun is 24*365,25 hours, not 365*24. And that's caused by the fact that the day is not 24 hours long (it's a couple of minutes shorter). This is why we have a leap year - we are paying the "debt" by adding another day, made out of the quarters we collected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would seem that **yes: there are still leap years**

*[Memory Beta](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Year)* doesn't have much to say on the matter unfortunately.

According to *[Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Year#Year)*:

> One Earth year was equal to 365.2425 Earth days in the Gregorian
>   calendar. **To compensate for the fraction of a day, a leap day was
>   added to every year whose number was divisible by four**, unless it was
>   a century, unless it was divisible by 400. These leap years consisted
>   of adding an extra day to the month of February. Instead of the usual
>   28 days, there would be 29.

Now, this explains the situation as it currently stands; because there seems to be no mention of removing leap years, we could assume that they still exist.

Furthermore, the introduction of [Stardates](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Stardate) did not impact our local Earth calendar:

> Stardates did not replace clock time **or everyday units for expressing
>   larger timespans, such as days, weeks, months, years**, centuries, or
>   millennia

Hence, it would seem that there has not been any modifications made to our current calendar system in the *Star Trek* universe, at least none mentioned which would impact the presence of a leap year.